# Error: Attempting to set key on an object that is immutable and has been frozen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, immutability

I am having a rather hard time tracking down the issue related to this error, obviously the implication is I'm trying to update an immutable object. Oddly, I have used this implementation before without a hitch which is why I am finding this behaviour so perplexing.

Below is the method I am using, it simply alters the object of an array, changing the property and returns the updated state. As referenced [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data), using `prevState` appears to be the optimal way for getting around immutability.

[image: Immutable Error]

```
onCheck = (id) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    prevState.options[id].checked = !prevState.options[id].checked;
    return {
      options: prevState.options,
      dataSource: prevState.cloneWithRows(prevState.options)
    };
  });
}
```

I have also tried a number of variations of copying the prevState, however it is still giving me the same immutability error. It appears as if it still references rather than duplicates the `prevState`.

```
 onCheck = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let options = [...prevState.options];
      options[id].checked = !options[id].checked;
      return {
        options: options,
        dataSource: this.state.cloneWithRows(options)
      };
    });
  }
```

Comment: You're mutating `prevState` in your function. You can't. You need to clone `prevState.options`, change *that*, then set it as new `options`.

Comment: That is perfectly acceptable, as I have used that implementation before, not to mention it is directly referenced in the documentation? Unless you can demonstrate otherwise?

Comment: How is this referenced in the documentation? The doc shows how to pass a function to `setState` which allows you to *access* `prevState`, but in which example is it mutating it?

Comment: The first snippet uses `concat` which manipulates the prevState?

Comment: No it doesn't; `concat` returns a new Array.

Comment: concat does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

Comment: Ah good spot! That being said, manipulating using the prevState seems perfectly fine, in which case the same functionality should be achievable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually found a solution, it appears I needed to copy not just the array but each element of the array. As the individual elements / objects of the array are still immutable / frozen.

```
onCheck = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const newOptions = prevState.options.map((option, index) => {
        let copyOption = {...option};
        if (id == index) {
          copyOption.checked = !copyOption.checked;
        }
        return copyOption;
      });
      return {
        options: newOptions,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newOptions)
      };
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you acknowledge that you are mutating the state, which you cannot do. A fix for this is to clone prevState.options before fiddling with it.

eg.

```
var options = Object.assign({}, prevState.options)
options[id].checked
return {
      options,
...
```

Comment: I am still getting the same immutability issue, it appears to still be referencing the state rather than creating a new object?

Answer (score 0):

As your [reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) pointed out, you should not directly mutate your data like you do

```
prevState.options[id].checked = !prevState.options[id].checked;
```

In your link, they return a new array by `concat` or by "spread syntax" (...). So i suggest you to copy your `prevState` first and mutate it

```
let state = [...prevState.options];
state[id].checked = !state[id].checked;
...
```

Comment: I am still getting the same immutable error as above? I had in fact tried this approach, however still no success.

Comment: Can you update the format of your `prevState.options[id]` ?